# How to deserialize Json string from Kafka topic in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, serialization, spring-kafka

I created a POJO to map a payload received from a Kafka topic.
It works if the format of payload is:

```
{"payload":{"name":notification,"key":"2637","message":"This is a notif"}
```

When I produce this message of JSON string type.

```
"{\"payload\":{\"name\":\"notification\",\"key\":\"2637\",\"message\":\"This is a notif\"}"
```

It is throwing

> Could not read JSON:Cannot construct instance of myfilename : no sting-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from string value.

How to fix it?

Comment: According to the logs, Your POJO class is missing the Parameterized Constructor. Try adding it.

Comment: You nee to show your actual code.

Comment: how are you doing the mapping right now? do you have some more code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to use a StringDeserializer if the message is just a String representing escaped JSON, and handle the message as a String. I don't think you can automatically bind to a POJO because it is not an actual JSON object.

You could write a custom deserializer to convert the String then delegate to an ObjectMapper.

Comment: But if you are consuming escaped JSON (my understanding of your problem) it might be worth talking to whoever is responsible for producing those messages.

Comment: Thanks, I agree. I will deserialize the JSON and pass that message directly. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue possibly could be resolved by using below setting in the mapper :

`mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT);`

On the side note, if you are already using `spring-kafka`, you can use the default `JsonDesrializer` or a custom deserializer.

```
consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
```

More documentations are available in the [spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#serdes)

Another ref : [Deserialize kafka messages in KafkaConsumer using springboot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60928034/serialize-kafka-messages-in-springboot/60928497#60928497)