# Deserialize kafka messages in KafkaConsumer using springboot

Tags: json, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a springboot app that listen kafka messages and convert them to object

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "test", groupId = "group_id")
public void consume(String message) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Hostel hostel = objectMapper.readValue(message, Hostel.class);
}
```

I woder if it is possible to do ti directly

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "test", groupId = "group_id")
public void consume(Hostel hostel) throws IOException { 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using `spring-kafka`. But then you need to use a [custom deserializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#serdes-mapping-types) (or a `JsonDeserializer`) in the container factory

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "test", groupId = "my.group", containerFactory = "myKafkaFactory")
fun genericMessageListener(myRequest: MyRequest, ack: Acknowledgment) {
//do Something with myRequest
ack.acknowledge()
}
```

Your ContainerFactory will look something like

```
@Bean
fun myKafkaFactory(): ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, MyRequest> {
val factory = ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, MyRequest>()
factory.consumerFactory = DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory(configProps(), StringDeserializer(), MyRequestDeserializer())
factory.containerProperties.ackMode = ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL
return factory
}
```

Your Deserialiser will look like

```
public class MyRequestDeserializer implements Deserializer {
private static ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

@Override
public void configure(Map map, boolean b) {
}

@Override
public MyRequest deserialize(String arg0, byte[] msgBytes) {
    try {
        return objectMapper.readValue(new String(msgBytes), MyRequest.class);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        log.warn("JSON parse/ mapping exception occurred. ", ex);
        return new MyRequest();
    }
}

@Override
public void close() {
    log.debug("MyRequestDeserializer closed");
}
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the default `JsonDeserializer` as given in [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#json)

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to create generic deserializer? I have a lot of message-s that I handle through Kafka and don't like the idea to create deserializer for each different message. Thanks!

Comment: Ideally, you should have only one type of message in a topic. Normally, one producer cannot produce different type of messages, and each type of message will need a different handler on consuming. So, I strongly suggest to have a separate topic per type.

If you insist, one way could be to return an `Object` in the deserialize method, and then a chain of try catches to deserialize in one of the know patterns, and then return it. While processing, you can do a type cast.